# What solution can truly replace Google Translator Toolkit?

Tags: web-apps, translation

Sad to see that [Google Translator Toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translator_Toolkit) closes in less than a month, as I have not been able to find a replacement that can do what we need:

- Full page HTML editing shown side by side (source<->translation).
- Special tag for sections to be locked (non-translatable). The Google Toolkit supported adding `class="notranslate"` to a tag to achieve that.
- WYSIWYG: Rendering of basic HTML, so e.g. bold, italic and bullet text is rendered.

In addition to the traditional requirements to a CAT tool:

- Online collaboration
- Upload and download of Translation Memory

I have done some research and there are a lot of tools that are claimed to replace the Google Toolkit, but when I investigate, none of them supports the 3 first points in this post.

Any suggestions?